# Finding the sum of two numbers knowing only the primes

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, prime-factorization

Pretend $N_1$ is the prime factorization of 30 and $N_2$ is the prime factorization of 8. Is there a way, using only $N_1$ and $N_2$, to get the prime factorization of the sum, 38?

It is easy to do product (just merge the prime factors) but I do not know about addition.

Comment: What ever algorithm you make will probably be more complicated than just factoring the sum. Guessing that's not the point though?

Comment: @jameselmore right; I am working with some large numbers in a program and I can't store the full value, so I am trying to store the prime factorization instead to save memory.

Comment: I don't know if it works in a general setting but in this case $N_1 = 2\cdot3\cdot5$ and $N_2 = 2^3$ so
\begin{equation}
2\cdot3\cdot5 + 2^3 = 2(3 \cdot 5 + 2^4) = 2\cdot19 = N_3
\end{equation}
and 19 happens to be prime, so $N_3$ is the prime factorization of 38.

Comment: How big are the numbers you mean?  Many languages have packages available that handle arbitrary size integers, freeing you from a $2^{64}$ limit.  Storing factorizations means you cannot represent many of the numbers-any with prime factors too large to store.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am doing this in C++ for something work-related and I can't use bignums for this

Comment: Suppose $N_1 = 13$ and $N_2 = 17$. Both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are prime factorizations (as both are already prime). When you add them  you get $13 + 17 = 30$, which is not a prime factorization, instead the result is a composite. Then for large integers this would become the problem of factoring in the case your result is a composite similar to this small example, which in itself if considered a "hard" problem. The security of encryption schemes like RSA are based on this assumption, so I'm not sure if you will be able to get the result you want.

Comment: One work around I've used for storing large numbers (which may make factoring a little tricky...) is making an array of integer values, and storing 10+ digits per entry. Frees you up quite a bit for taking products and summing very large numbers. Division is a slightly different story however...

Comment: @Alex You meant $2(3 \cdot 5 + 2^2)$ not $2(3 \cdot 5 + 2^4)$, which through me off, but that is nice start. More generally, you can factor out any common prime factors, then you just have to worry about adding and refactoring the least common factor.

Comment: I've been wondering about this too, since I figured encodings based on prime factorizations had potential for more efficiently storing exact fractions. To make the problem statement clearer, you would have to add that what you want is something faster, or PERHAPS, though not likely, more memory efficient, than just multiplying all the factors together, adding them, then refactoring, preferably consistently faster and the fastest method you can find.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it a little easier by looking for common factors.  In your example, $2$ is an element of both factorizations, so will be a factor of the sum.  If there are lots of common factors, that will help a lot.  Otherwise, not so much ...

Comment: are there some general results ( assuming for example that $y$ and $x$ have no common divisors) that connect the prime factorisation of $(x+y)$ to that of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou:  Not that I am aware of.  Addition and factoring don't play nicely together.

Comment: Take $47$ and $53$. Their sum is $100$, yet both are prime. You need more than just a prime factorization to factor a sum - you need to know the remainders modulo all the primes and prime powers less than the two numbers also and look for cases where the sums of the two numbers  modulo those primes - and prime powers potentially - cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is pretty much hopeless. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ both have easy but disjoint factorisations (many small factors but not the same ones in $N_1$ and $N_2$), then $N_3$ is quite likely to involve by contrast some very large prime factor(s). The [ABC-conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) makes a precise (but not so easy to formulate) statement to this effect. It hasn't been proved, but then it hasn't been disproved either.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you closer:

$$\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{(30 + 8)}{gcd(30 +8,lcm(30,8))}=\frac{19}{lcm(30,8)}=\frac{19}{120}$$

where $gcd(\cdot,\cdot)$ is greatest common denominator and $lcm(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the lowest common multiple